# Get Value from Key Value array

Tags: jquery, arrays, key-value

I have an array with key value pairs.

```
var array=[
             {Key:"Name",Value:"Sam" },
             {Key:"Marks",Value:"50"},
             {Key:"Subject",Value:"English"},
          ];
```

I want to push `Value` of object whose `Key` is 'Subject' into a variable. I tried to see how Value can be accessed but failed at the very first step.
How can this be done?

```
for (var key in array[0])
{
    console.log(key[i].Value); //error:  Cannot read property 'Value' of undefined
}
```

How can I push `Value` of object whose `Key` is 'Subject' into a variable?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aghosh08/bkh3wasa/

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: Please consider a higher-quality reference site, such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference).

Comment: Yeah. You're right. @T.J.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `for-in` loop is on the `array[0]` object, so `key` is a key (property name) for that object. So this:

```
console.log(key[i].Value);
```

should be

```
console.log(array[0][key].Value);
```

**But**, given what you've said you want to do, I'm not seeing any need for a `for-in` loop:

> I want to push Value of object whose Key is 'Subject' into a variable.

[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (which is new in ES2015 -- aka ES6 -- but easily shimmed/polyfilled) is useful for this:

```
var entry = array.find(function(e) { return e.Key === "Subject"; });
if (entry) {
    theVariable = entry.Value;
}
```

If you're using ES2015 (which still means transpiling, for now), you can use an arrow function to be more concise:

```
let entry = array.find(e => e.Key === "Subject");
if (entry) {
    theVariable = entry.Value;
}
```

But if you want to stick to things in ES5 and earlier, there's [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
array.some(function(e) {
    if (e.Key === "Subject") {
        theVariable = e.Value;
        return true; // stops the "loop"
    }
});
```

Comment: Damn, you are fast.

Answer (score 1):

sorry i misunderstood the question before - edited

I suggest using the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method for this

```js
var array=[ {Key:"Name",Value:"Sam" }, {Key:"Marks",Value:"50"}, {Key:"Subject",Value:"English"}, ]; 

$.each(array, function() { 
     if(this.Key === "Subject"){ 
        this.Value = "something" 
     } 
}); 

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array=[
        {Key:"Name",Value:"Sam" },
        {Key:"Marks",Value:"50"},
        {Key:"Subject",Value:"English"},
    ];
var i=0;
var value;
for(array as value) {
    value[i]=$(this).text();
    i++;
    alert(value[i]);
}
```

Try this with key and value