# Passing jQuery dictionary object to an input field

Tags: c#, jquery

```
var dictionary = [];

dictionary.push({
                key:"Res01" ,
                value: "Loss of internet connection at location"
            });
```

**when adding this dictionary object to an input field**

```
$('#hdnNotesDict').val('');
$('#hdnNotesDict').val(dictionary);
```

i am not getting the dictionary value in that input field.

getting result as: `[object,object]`

Thanks in advance and any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Depending on what value you want try with `$('#hdnNotesDict').val(dictionary[0].value);`

Comment: Hi @CarstenLøvboAndersen
I have tried that also but if i have 100 values in dictionary then it will not work.

Comment: and also i wanted to store key and value both in that field.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461762/get-value-from-key-value-array

Comment: How exactly you want to display the dictionary values in a textbox?

Comment: i need dictionary values like :

0:
{key: "1",
value: "sdasdasfsfsfs"}
So that i can use that input field values at controller for manipulations.

Comment: You need to create a string by iterating thru the dictionary... or you can try converting dictionary to JSON string by doing JSON.Stringify. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162749/convert-js-object-to-json-string

Comment: Thanks @ChetanRanpariya it solved my criteria in jquery but at controller post method i am getting that value in variable like Dictionary<string, string> hdnNotesDict and resulting as count 0 .

Comment: yes, because you send string of array of objects in your controller you should convert it back from jstring to object

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this form in your view:

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="kvps" name="kvps" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and you put some values like that:

```
(function () {
    $('#submit').mousedown(function () {
        let input = $('#kvps');
        let dict = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            dict.push({ key: `Res${i}`, val: `Val${i}` });
        }

        input.val(JSON.stringify(dict));
    });
})();
```

in this case you convert the array in a string and you should take it as string into your controller
BUT - you cannot convert it to dictionary immediately, first you should map it to array of model with the same property names then you can call ToDictionary over it.

Array example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult JInput(string kvps)
    {
        var arr = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object[]>(kvps);

        return this.View();
    }
```

If you need it as Dictionary<string, string> you schould use in your jquery object instead:

```
    (function () {
        $('#submit').mousedown(function () {
            let input = $('#kvps');
            let dict = {};

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                // watch out for the keys here to not overwrite the values
                dict[`Res${i}`] = `Val${i}`;
            }

            input.val(JSON.stringify(dict));
        });
    })();
```

And in your controller like that:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult JInput(string kvps)
    {
        var arr = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(kvps);

        return this.View();
    }
```